# Python can't print the word from the given condition

Tags: python

I have this program:

```
def validateNumber(number):
    if (count > 10) :
        print('Invalid number')
        return -1
    elif (count < 10):
        print('Invalid number')
        return -1

while True:
    count = 0
    num =  int(input('Number:'))
    while num > 0:
        num = num//10
        count = count+1
    if (count == 10) :
        break
```

But I can't print the print('Invalid number') and it turn out to be like this:

```
Number:122344
Number:123442
Number:1234567890
>>>
```

I want it to print the print('Invalid number') when the number is less or more than 10.

```
Number:122344
Invalid number
Number:123442088080989098
Invalid number
Number:1234567890
>>>
```

Help please. Thanks

The return -1 is for if the number is missing or invalid

Comment: You don't have to have two loops. One is enough.

Comment: Also you dont need an elif, you can do:
if  (count > 10) or  (count < 10):

Comment: @LuisLeal Or `count != 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you could condense your `if` check to one statement. Note that the easiest way to count the number of digits is to convert it to a string and check its length.

```
def validateNumber(number):
    if len(str(number)) != 10:
        return -1
```

Unfortunately, you do not return a legitimate value if the `number` is valid. Why not return a boolean value instead?

```
def validateNumber(number):
    if len(str(number)): 
        return True
    return False
```

You can further reduce this to:

```
def validateNumber(number):
    return len(str(number)) == 10
```

Note that all the validation logic has now been moved to the function. You'll see how this simplifies the loop code.

Next, you have defined two loops. When you break from the inner, the outer will continue, so you come back to the inner, thus restarting the process.

As a fix, I'd recommend doing this with one loop *only*, like this:

```
while True:
    x = int(input('...'))
    if validateNumber(x):
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid Number')
```

Since `validateNumber` returns a `bool` result, simply have the `if` query the return value, and `break` if the number is valid, otherwise the loop repeats.

The good thing about having all your validation code inside the function is that you don't have to modify your loop code if your validation logic changes.

Comment: how to make it works if I want to use it with return -1 if the number is invalid?

Comment: @Joehan Well, if the number is valid, what should it return? Please open a new question with more details.

Comment: it will stop repeating...ok ill open a new question

Comment: @Joehan Obviously, but what should the _function_ return?

Comment: @Joehan No, the question has been closed already. I'd really appreciate if you could open a new question. Thank you :-)